# ArrayAdapter values not changing

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
public class UnitListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Unit> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Unit> units;
    private MeasurementType type;
    private static HashMap<String, Double> unitValues;

    public void setMeasurementType(MeasurementType measurementType) {
        type = measurementType;
    }

    public void setUnitValues(HashMap<String, Double> newValues) {
        unitValues.clear();
        unitValues = newValues;
    }

    public void setUnits(ArrayList<Unit> newUnits) {
        units = newUnits;
    }
}
```

Above is the implementation of `ArrayAdapter` minus the `getView()` and `getCount()` methods. Now, in my activity I have this method:

```
public void updateUnitAdapter(ArrayList<Unit> units, final MeasurementType measurementType) {
        //change the type
        unitAdapter.setMeasurementType(measurementType);
        //set the hashmap unit values
        unitValues = new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
            put(measurementType.getType(), DEFAULT_VALUE);
        }};

        //clear the current units for the previous measurement type
        unitAdapter.clear();

        //add the new units for the new measurement type
        for(Unit u : units) {
            unitAdapter.add(u);
        }

        //update the list view
        unitAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

but when I step through in the debugger, it gets to the `getView()` method and when I check these variables, they are haven't changed to the new ones that I am setting them too, they stay the same...is there something I am not understanding about `ArrayAdapter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` has its **own** internal collection, which is modified when you call `add()` or `clear()`. In this case you are updating it, but (from your comments) it looks like you have also overriden `getCount()` and `getView()` to get those values from somewhere else (possibly the `units` member?).

If that's the case, you should update `units` intead of calling `clear()`/`add()`.

Otherwise, remove the `units` field altogether and use `getItem()` to access the collection items.